# Oracle SQL Statement Compare Between 2 Value Different Document Type

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wish to query out all the transaction data inside this transaction table and sum them accordingly. The data inside the table as below:

```
Company   PO      Document No   Document Type  Amount  
001       PO-001    222           OR            2.2
001       PO-001    222           OR            3.3  
001       PO-001    444           OP            4.4
001       PO-001    444           OP            5.5
001       PO-002    555           OP            1.2
001       PO-002    666           OR            1.2
```

As long as the total amount for same PO number but different document type no tally i should show them as Output below:

```
Company   PO     Document_No  DocumentType_OR  Amount DocumentType_OP Amount_PO  
 001      PO-001    222           OR              5.5         OP         9.9
```

Didn't you have any advise how should i do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: `GROUP BY` with `SUM`.

Comment: Please spell out the logic for your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group by` and `Sum` the `Amount`

```
select Company,PO,"Document No","Document Type",sum(Amount) as Amount
from yourtable
Where PO = 'PO-001'
group by Company,PO,"Document No","Document Type"
```

**Update :** Use `conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT Company,
       PO,
       Min([Document No]),
       Max(CASE WHEN "Document Type" = 'OR' THEN "Document Type" END) As Document_Type_OR,
       Sum(CASE WHEN "Document Type" = 'OR' THEN amount END) AS Amount_OR,
       Max(CASE WHEN "Document Type" = 'OP' THEN "Document Type" END) As Document_Type_OP,
       Sum(CASE WHEN "Document Type" = 'OP' THEN amount END) AS Amount_PO
FROM   Yourtable
WHERE  PO = 'PO-001'
GROUP  BY Company,PO
```

Comment: @PM77-1 you should not use `Square brackets` in oracle to escape the `space` use double quotes `"`

Comment: @PM77-1: Sorry i just edit my output pattern. It should be like that any advise i can do it?

Comment: @goh6319 -your expected output deosn't make sense to me `Document_No = 222` doesn't have `DocumentType = OP` how you got that in ouptut.